# In Nifi, Custom Processor with Hive database connection pooling service not working

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am developing custom processor with hive database connection pooling service. Added necessary dependency in pom file and added necessary folders in custom processor folder. I have created class file and able to generate nar file. Placed nar file in lib directory and restarted nifi server. Its look like everything working fine. But services are not showing in database connection dropdown box. Instead it showing connection id, but every time services are creating when click "create" in controller section. For other processors, it seems working fine.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to link a processor to a controller service, you need two
dependencies:

- The processor project needs a provided dependency on the JAR where
  the service interface is
- The NAR project needs a NAR dependency on the NAR where the service
  interface is

In the case of Hive, the interface and implementation are both in
nifi-hive-processors which get packaged into nifi-hive-nar, so you
need:

In your processors pom.xml:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-hive-processors</artifactId>
        <version>replace with the version of NiFi you are using</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In your NAR pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-hive-nar</artifactId>
        <version>replace with the version of NiFi you are using</version>
        <type>nar</type>
    </dependency>
```